# How to read in a list of files to a single data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am using R.  I have a series of txt files that all all `;` seperated.  I want to combined those files into 1 data frame. Each individual file has the variable names in the top row.

I found a useful post for doing this online.  [How to import multiple .csv files at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once).  I am using `rbindlist` to do this, though I am open to suggestions if there is an easier way to import this data.

Here is my code.

```
# create list of files
temp <- NULL
temp <-  as.list (list.files ("F:/Desktop/data"))
temp

# now rbind the list using rbindlist
data <- NULL
data <- rbindlist(temp, fill=FALSE, idcol=NULL)

is.list (temp)
typeof (temp)
```

When I run this code, I get an error

```
Error in rbindlist(temp, fill = FALSE, idcol = NULL) : 
  Item 1 of input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
```

However, when I check temp using is.list and typeof, it shows up as a list.  I am not sure why rbindlist isn't reading the list as a list.  Is rbindlist the best way to import this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `list.files` is just giving the file names.  We need to read those files.  As we are using `rbindlist` from `data.table`, read with `fread` and then use the `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
temp <- list.files ("F:/Desktop/data", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.txt$")
out <- rbindlist(lapply(temp, fread), fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you.  This coded worked great for my project.